# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

Como resolvo este erro?

> Java - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Cliente.CadastroCliente(Cliente.java:43) at Operacoes.main(Operacoes.java:9)

Segue meu código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Cliente { 

    private String nome; 
    private String telefone; 
    private int codigo; 
    private String rua; 

    void setRua(String z) { 
        rua = z; 
    } 
    void setTelefone(String t) { 
       telefone = t; 
    } 
    void setCodigo(int n) { 
        codigo = n; 
    } 
    void setNome(String name) { 
        nome = name; 
    }

    Cliente cliente[] = new Cliente[30]; 

    void CadastroCliente(int n) { 

        cliente[n].setCodigo(n); 
        cliente[n].setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: ")); 
        Endereco endereco = new Endereco(); 
        endereco.setLogradouro(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Logradouro: ")); 
        endereco.setNumero(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nº: "))); 
        endereco.setComplemento(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Complemento: ")); 
        endereco.setCidade(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cidade: ")); 
        endereco.setEstado(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Estado: ")); 
        endereco.setCep(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("CEP: ")); 
        cliente[n].setRua(rua); 

    } 
}
```

O meu compilador Java diz que está tudo OK, mas quando tento executar com o método `main` dá o erro.

Aqui está o `main`:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Operacoes { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Cliente teste1 = new Cliente(); 
        teste1.CadastroCliente(1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Igor, bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. Tenha em conta, em futuros postes, a edição que fiz na sua pergunta.

Comment: E quando informar um número de linha de um erro, informe qual é a linha deste número, não é fácil identificar quando posta em algum lugar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

O fato de um programa compilar não significa que ele esteja certo.

Este código está bem confuso, você está misturando GUI com dados.

Você precisa inicializar os elementos do vetor antes de utilizá-los. Você está tentando gravar dados em um estado nulo. Teria que mudar o código para algo assim:

```
void CadastroCliente(int n) {
    cliente[n] = new Cliente();
    cliente[n].setCodigo(n); 
    ...
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ObjectInit.java).

Ainda não é uma boa solução mas resolve seu problema. Você colocar um *array* de uma classe dentro desta própria classe é muito esquisito. Mais cedo ou mais tarde você terá outras consequências ruins.