# Problemas ao executar classe em Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Quando vou invocar o método desta classe:

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Operacoes {

    /*
     DESENVOLVIDO BY: "IIJM Team"
     */

    Cliente clientes;
    ArrayList<Cliente> cliente;


    public Operacoes() {
        cliente = new ArrayList<>();        
    }

    int aux = 0;

    public void cadastroCliente() {
        aux++;
        clientes.setCodigo(aux); // O erro ocorre quando chega aqui!
        clientes.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog((aux)
                + "º Cliente\nNome: "));
        clientes.setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("E-mail: "));

        cliente.add(clientes);

    }
 }
```

Aparece o seguinte problema:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Classe do método `main`:

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Operacoes op = new Operacoes();
            op.cadastroCliente(); // Ocorre um erro aqui também
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, tenta editar tua questão colocando a saída completa do erro.

Comment: Informe qual a linha onde o erro ocorre (não só o número porque não temos como saber qual é o número aqui, mostre a linha)

Comment: Na classe Programa ocorre na linha 9, na classe Operacoes ocorre na linha 23;

Comment: Como o @bigown disse, nós não temos como saber qual é o número da linha, mostre a linha.

Comment: @bigown e Jéferson coloquei comentários nas linhas que o erro ocorre.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49013/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Comment: @bigown Obrigado por me lembrar, e obrigado por sempre está me ajudando! Forte abraço. Obs: tenho apenas 16 anos e quando crescer quero ser como você...

Comment: @IgorAlisson [esta conta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21284/igor-gutemberg) também é sua? Se for, me avise, podemos fundir as duas se quiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variável `clientes` não foi instanciada.

Tudo o que precisa fazer é instanciá-la (`clientes = new Cliente()`).

```
public void cadastroCliente() {
    clientes = new Cliente(); //adicione esta linha
    aux++;
    clientes.setCodigo(aux); // O erro ocorre quando chega aqui!
    clientes.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog((aux) + "º Cliente\nNome: "));
    clientes.setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("E-mail: "));

    cliente.add(clientes);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa instanciar a classe `Cliente` na variável `clientes` antes de usá-la. Mas eu melhoria este código um pouco mais, assim:

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Operacoes {
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;

    public Operacoes() {
        cliente = new ArrayList<Cliente>(); //note que mudei os nomes para ficar menos confuso
    }

    public void cadastroCliente() {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        int aux = clientes.size() + 1; //pega a quantidade de elementos atual e incrementa
        cliente.setCodigo(aux);
        cliente.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog((aux)
                + "º Cliente\nNome: "));
        cliente.setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("E-mail: "));

        clientes.add(cliente);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Instanciate.java).

Note que pequenas mudanças simplificaram bastante o código.

Sua lógica está bem complicada, você continuará tendo outros problemas montando código deste jeito. Eu acho que eu já havia falado isto para você em outra pergunta mas como a pergunta não está em sua conta você provavelmente criou outra conta.

Só uma coisa boba que ajuda entender o programa. Você está criando uma variável que vai guardar **um** cliente e chama ela de `clientes`. E cria uma variável que vai guardar vários clientes e chama ela de `cliente`. Vai funcionar mas esta inconsistência faz o pensamento correto mais difícil. Uma dessas variáveis provavelmente deveria ser local. A variável `aux` provavelmente não deveria existir. O nome desta classe `Operacoes` parece não se um nome apropriado. De outra forma talvez esta classe nem deveria existir. Me parece que está criando uma classe apenas por criar.

Comment: Por que a minha lógica está complicada? Seja mais especifico.

Comment: Teria muita coisa para dizer além do que eu já disse. Viraria um curso.

Comment: Na verdade a variável 'max' não existe acho que você se referiu a 'aux' mas ela tem que existe por que a cada cliente registrado soma mais 1 essa é minha intenção. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Isto, eu digitei errado. Não existe razão para ela existir.