# Null.point.exception ao executar método de outra classe

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou executando este código:

classe de execução

```
package aloiexecv2;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
public class test {

    private static Variaveis variaveis;
    private static Dados dados;
    private static Cadastrar cadastrar;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int opcao;
        System.out.println("\n----------CADASTRO DE ROTINAS DE INICIALIZAÇÃO----------");
        System.out.println("Neste script você pode adicionar comandos para inicializar rotinas (no formato: startx ou xcalic -c) ou");
        System.out.println("Pode acrescentar o atalho para um programa que será executado (no formato: /home/usuario/programa)");
        System.out.println("Escolha sua opção:");
        System.out.println("1) Cadastrar rotina ou programa");
        System.out.println("2) Excluir script");
        System.out.println("3) Pré-visualizar arquivo do incialização");
        System.out.println("4) Sair");
        opcao = Variaveis.getENTRADA().nextInt();
        if (opcao >= 1 && opcao <= 4) {
            **cadastrar.CadRotina(opcao);**

        } else {
            System.out.println("Opcao inválida! Digite novamente");
        }
    }

}
```

Metodo da Classe Cadastrar:

```
public void CadRotina(String arquivo, String texto, int opcao) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    this.arquivo = arquivo;
    this.texto = texto;
    this.opcao = opcao;
    dados.gravarNoArquivo(arquivo, texto);
}
public void CadRotina(int opcao2) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    this.opcao = opcao2;
    switch (opcao2) {
        case 1:
            if (arquivo == null) {
                System.out.println("\n----------INFORMANDO AS ROTINAS DE INICIALIZAÇÃO----------");
                System.out.println("Cadastre primeiramente o nome do arquivo que recebera as rotinas");
                this.arquivo = Variaveis.getENTRADA().nextLine();
                System.out.println("Agora, informe o caminho do script que devera ser executado automaticamente(Ex.: /home/scriptinternet: \n Ou adicione uma linha de comando (ex. xcalib - c)");
                this.texto = Variaveis.getENTRADA().nextLine();
                dados.gravarNoArquivo(arquivo, texto);

            }
    }
}
```

E ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   aloiexecv2.test.main(test.java:34)
>   /root/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned:
>   1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)**

A linha 34 refere-se ao método `CadRotina(opcao)`. Aparentemente o java ta dizendo que o método está vazio, mas já testei a variável opção e ela esta sendo setada no `Scanner`.

Fiz uma sobrecarga de método para que pudesse utilizar o CadRotina tanto com a variavel opcao quanto para execução direta (gravar arquivo, texto).

Não entendo por quê não executa. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51604/problemas-ao-executar-classe-em-java

Comment: `cadastrar` não foi instanciado

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%C3%A9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%C3%A3o-suas-principais-causas)

Comment: Relacionada: [Programa para criação de script de inicialização java (dica)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217187/132)

Answer (score 0):

**1) Use a referência ao invés do tipo:**

```
opcao = Variaveis.getENTRADA().nextInt();
```

Troque por:

```
opcao = variaveis.getENTRADA().nextInt();
```

**2) Estático não gera objeto:**

```
private static Variaveis variaveis;
private static Dados dados;
private static Cadastrar cadastrar;
```

Troque por:

```
private Variaveis variaveis;
private Dados dados;
private Cadastrar cadastrar;
```