# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Calculadora

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Comecei a estudar Orientação a Objetos e resolvi fazer um programa simples de calculadora. No momento fiz apenas a soma para ver se o modo que eu estava fazendo está certo.

Segue o código:

```
package javaapplication100;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Marcielli
 */
public class JavaApplication100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Calculadora calc = new Calculadora();

        System.out.println("Digite:\n+ - Somar\n* - Multiplicar\n/ - Dividir\n- - Subtrair");
        String escolha = input.nextLine();

        switch (escolha) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println("Somar quantos numeros? ");
                int a = input.nextInt();            

                calc.setNumerosSomar(a);//Esta acusando erro aqui.
                //calc.setNumerosSomar(calc.qntNumeros = input.nextInt());                
                System.out.println("A soma: "+calc.getNumerosSomar());
                break;
            case "*":
                break;
            case "/":
                break;
            case "-":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Calculadora {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    protected double[] numerosSomar;
    private double[] numerosMultiplicar;
    private double[] numerosDividir;
    private double[] numerosSubtrair;
    public int qntNumeros;
    public double resSoma;
    public double resMultiplicar;
    public double resDividir;
    public double resSubtrair;

    public void setNumerosSomar(int a) {

        this.qntNumeros = a;

        for(int i=0; i<qntNumeros; i++) {

            System.out.println("Digite um numero: ");
            numerosSomar[i] = input.nextDouble(); //Esta acusando erro aqui.

        }

       for(int i=0; i<qntNumeros; i++) {

            resSoma+=numerosSomar[i];

        }     

    }

    public double getNumerosSomar() {

        return resSoma;

    }
}
```

Realmente não tenho certeza se estou fazendo qualquer coisa correta, pois ainda estou tentando entender o conceito da Orientação a Objetos como um todo.

O problema que estou tendo é o erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Deixei um comentário nas linhas que a IDE está apontando que está com problema. Mas por via das dúvidas seguem elas abaixo:

```
calc.setNumerosSomar(a);

numerosSomar[i] = input.nextDouble();
```

A minha dúvida aqui é a seguinte, é um erro de lógica? Porque eu acredito que o problema não seja no método, pois se eu digitei `2` na `qntNumeros` (variável utilizada para determinar quando o for irá parar), essa variável vai estar valendo `2`.

O loop `for` está de `0 < qntNumeros(que vale 2)`. Aqui me parece não haver erro algum.

Eu também não vejo erro na linha `numerosSomar[i] = input.nextDouble();`, pois realmente acredito que é assim que se guarda um valor em um vetor de tipo double.

Olhando essa pergunta [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NullPointerException](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49013/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception) eu acredito que eu estou tentando gravar dados em um estado nulo, e que preciso inicializar o vetor antes. Mas não entendi como eu devo inicializar o vetor antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é simples. Você não está declarando o valor inicial do array dos números.

```
protected double[] numerosSomar = new double[100];
private double[] numerosMultiplicar = new double[100];
private double[] numerosDividir = new double[100];
private double[] numerosSubtrair  = new double[100];
```

Testei com a mudança e deu tudo OK

Obs.: esse valor "100" dentro da declaração do array é o valor máximo que ele pode alocar ou seja ou valor do "Quantos números você deseja..."

Comment: Nossa, bem simples mesmo. Eu pensei que eu poderia deixar em aberto, independente de quantos números fossem digitados. Agora entendi, obrigada. ;)

Comment: Depois dá uma pesquisada em Collections no Java, elas podem resolver o problema de quando a gente não sabe quantos valores vão entrar ou sair dessa lista de dados, como é o seu caso. Abraço.

Comment: Ah legal, vou pesquisar já. Obrigada. Abraço.